# Expanding container around dynamically added fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

In internet explorer, when I have a field dynamically generated, everything moves down. However, the surrounding container stays the same height and everything just moves on past it.

Try clicking 'Add a Language' or 'Add a Skill' then scroll down to the bottom.

Any suggestions?

**http://quspot.com/ie_test/**

[image: Any suggestions?]

EDIT/

The syntax is

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

.wrapper is expanding just fine (I added a background color to make sure), the #content div is not though.

Comment: Can you post any of your existing code... HTML, CSS???

Comment: Are you aware that some of your divs are "cleafix" instead of "clearfix"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does adding `overflow:hidden;` to the container div help?

---

#### Update after link provided

it's something to do with the `.clearfix`, I think there's too many of them applied, and they're inheriting in weird ways

I changed the `reset .clearfix` from:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

to:

```
.clearfix {overflow: hidden;}
```

and it stopped happening, though while that clearfix method works for this form it may not site wide, so you may wan to look at which divs you actually need clearfix on, you should only need it on the `content_body` divs.. as you only want to contain the floated form elements inside each of these

Comment: it's weird, adding `overflow:hidden;` just hides the rest of the page

Comment: OK sorry, I might delete this, I was thinking abut it the wrong way around  that IE was clearing and others weren't doh! - but I did just try your link in IE8 and it's OK?? - so will need to spend some time checking, as I can't see the problem yet ;)

Comment: Try clicking 'Add a Language' or 'Add a Skill' then scroll down to the bottom.

Comment: Got it.ta, have updated answer, it's too much external code to narrow it down, but hope that's a clue to help clean out which divs in your form actually need to contain their floats `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I sorta fixed it by adding the wrapper's properties diretly on the content and then doing this

```
<div id="content">
    CONTENT
    <br clear="all" />
</div>
```

But if anyone has a solution, I'd like to use the wrapper for when I need to add things **outside** the wrapper in the content area.

Comment: I think you solved it by adding the <br>. For some reason I remember IE needing that.